# Is it reasonable to save data as python modules?

Tags: python, data-persistence, dynamic-import

This is what I've done for a project. I have a few data structures that are bascially dictionaries with some methods that operate on the data. When I save them to disk, I write them out to .py files as code that when imported as a module will load the same data into such a data structure.

Is this reasonable? Are there any big disadvantages? The advantage I see is that when I want to operate with the saved data, I can quickly import the modules I need. Also, the modules can be used seperate from the rest of the application because you don't need a separate parser or loader functionality.

Comment: Both of the advantages you mention come back to the ability to load the data separate from any "loader" code -- and using a loader from a standard or 3rd-party library (pickle, SimpleJSON, YAML, etc) buys you that advantage also.

Comment: Python by default will also output .pyc files, which will nearly double the size of data overall.  Generally speaking, a baaad idea.  Have you considered sqlite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's reasonable, and I do it all the time. Obviously it's not a format you use to exchange data, so it's not a good format for anything like a save file.

But for example, when I do migrations of websites to Plone, I often get data about the site (such as a list of which pages should be migrated, or a list of how old urls should be mapped to new ones, aor lists of tags). These you typically get in Word och Excel format. Also the data often needs massaging a bit, and I end up with what for all intents and purposes are a dictionaries mapping one URL to some other information.

Sure, I *could* save that as CVS, and parse it into a dictionary. But instead I typically save it as a Python file with a dictionary. Saves code.

So, yes, it's reasonable, no it's not a format you should use for any sort of save file. It however often used for data that straddles the border to configuration, like above.

Answer (score 7):

By operating this way, you may gain some modicum of convenience, but you pay many kinds of price for that. The space it takes to save your data, and the time it takes to both save and reload it, go up substantially; and your security exposure is unbounded -- you must ferociously guard the paths from which you reload modules, as it would provide an easy avenue for any attacker to inject code of their choice to be executed under your userid (`pickle` itself is not rock-solid, security-wise, but, compared to this arrangement, it shines;-).

All in all, I prefer a simpler and more traditional arrangement: executable code lives in one module (on a typical code-loading path, that does not need to be R/W once the module's compiled) -- it gets loaded just once and from an already-compiled form. Data live in their own files (or portions of DB, etc) in any of the many suitable formats, mostly standard ones (possibly including multi-language ones such as JSON, CSV, XML, ... &c, if I want to keep the option open to easily load those data from other languages in the future).

Answer (score 3):

The biggest drawback is that it's a potential security problem since it's hard to guarantee that the files won't contains arbitrary code, which could be really bad. So don't use this approach if anyone else than you have write-access to the files.

Comment: No, I'm not worried about other people modifying the files.

Answer (score 3):

A reasonable option might be to use the [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module, which is specifically designed to save and restore python structures to disk.

Comment: But has the same security problem. And isn't easily editable.

Comment: Easily editable is good. :D Anyway, I was aware of Pickle, but that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 3):

Alex Martelli's answer is absolutely insightful and I agree with him.  However, I'll go one step further and make a specific recommendation: use JSON.

JSON is simple, and Python's data structures map well into it; and there are several standard libraries and tools for working with JSON.  The `json` module in Python 3.0 and newer is based on [simplejson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/), so I would use `simplejson` in Python 2.x and `json` in Python 3.0 and newer.

Second choice is XML.  XML is more complicated, and harder to just look at (or just edit with a text editor) but there is a vast wealth of tools to validate it, filter it, edit it, etc.

Also, if your data storage and retrieval needs become at all nontrivial, consider using an actual database.  [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) is terrific: it's small, and for small databases runs very fast, but it is a real actual SQL database.  I would definitely use a Python ORM instead of learning SQL to interact with the database; my favorite ORM for SQLite would be [Autumn](http://autumn-orm.org/) (small and simple), or the ORM from [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) (you don't even need to learn how to create tables in SQL!)  Then if you ever outgrow SQLite, you can move up to a real database such as [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/).  If you find yourself writing lots of loops that search through your saved data, and especially if you need to enforce dependencies (such as if foo is deleted, bar must be deleted too) consider going to a database.

Comment: Thanks for all the technologies and explenations. I didn't know all of them.